# insert & Database.insertImmediate not immediate?

Tags: apex, soql, insert

Baffled by a new record I've added that isn't available to query.

```
Person__c b = New Person__c(Name='Bob');
insert b;                                                                    //Returns a valid Id
Person_c newRecord = [SELECT Name FROM Person__c WHERE Id=:b.Id LIMIT 1];    //Returns NULL
```

I figured the insert operation might not have completed, so I tried:

```
Integer amount;
Database.SaveResult sr;

amount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Person__c];   //Returns 3
sObject s = new Person__c (Name='Bob');
sr = Database.insertImmediate(s);
if (sr.isSuccess()) System.Debug('Saved!'); //Shows saved
amount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Person__c];   //Returns 3 (expected 4)
```

Both of the above inserts work, but I can't seem to retrieve the new record within the same function. When I refresh the page, I can see there are now 4 records.

*This works in a timely manner as a logged in user or on Dev console.* Just not on guest. On guest, there is some sort of delay. The fact that the insert occurs (later) suggests I have the permissions set to Create + the field-level settings.

Am I missing a step such as "reindex" or "Database.refresh()"

Answer (score 0):

Guest user can't own a record, so a guest user sharing rule would need to be configured to provide read access to the record

Comment: Thank you for the replay.

Note: guest user successfully creates the record and can also read it. Only "later" by a few seconds. Seemingly after my code needed it

Comment: It could be the sequence of events for the sharing record creation. I believe that criteria based sharing rules are calculated asynchronously, so that's where the gap may be coming from. I'll see if I can find a link to support this once I'm back at desk.

Comment: Here is a previous answer that seems to support this theory: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375247/when-does-sharing-rule-execute/375250#375250

Comment: This is interesting. When I use "without sharing" there is no delay, which further seems to support the theory